# Reading encoded url in asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, urlencode

I am using this encoding/decoding javascript 64bit from here http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

so here is the scanrio: from JavaScript i am redireting to a new aspx page and on the page_load i am reading the QueryString id.

Everything working fine but the question is, if i want to encode/decode in asp.net in codebehind how would i do?

i am planning to encode before i redirect to a page from .JS but how would i read the encoded in asp.net code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything working fine but the question is, if i want to
>   encode/decode in asp.net in codebehind how would i do?

use below methods in code behind to encode and decode.

```
static public string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
{
    byte[] encodedDataAsBytes
        = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
    string returnValue =
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
    return returnValue;
}

static public string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
{
    byte[] toEncodeAsBytes
            = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
    string returnValue
            = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
    return returnValue;
}
```

> i am planning to encode before i redirect to a page from .JS but how
>   would i read the encoded in asp.net code behind?

you can call `DecodeFrom64` method to decode encoded text using JS.

**Test :**

```
 input = "Abu Hamzah"
 JS encoded text = "QWJ1IEhhbXphaA=="
```

`DecodeFrom64("QWJ1IEhhbXphaA==")` result is `"Abu Hamzah"` and `EncodeTo64("Abu Hamzah")` result is `"QWJ1IEhhbXphaA=="` as expected.

### **Edit:**

Add base64 encode decode java script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/webtoolkit.base64.js">
```

you can download it from here http://www.webtoolkit.info/djs/webtoolkit.base64.js

in your javascript you can call this method as below

```
window.location.href="mypage.aspx?id=" + Base64.encode('Test');
```

if you want to decode this query string parameter from server side, then you can use `DecodeFrom64` method

Comment: thanks for the detail answer, but i am still not sure, how the encode/decode will work from js,  somethign like this.. `window.location.href="mypage.aspx?id= + EncodeTo64("Test")` ? how does the javascript  have a ref to EncodeTo64 method?

Comment: you don't need to call C# method from js for encode and decode. use js functions for that. when you need to do it from code behind you can use C# methods. both encode and decode will give you same results.

Comment: i am getting this error `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected` i tried using like this in  js `window.location.href="mypage.aspx?id= + EncodeTo64("Test")`

Comment: i am getting this error now in DecodeFrom64 method `Invalid character in a Base-64 string.`

Comment: i have a guid id `37945704-cf86-4b2e-a4b5-0db0204902c8`

Comment: you need to give encoded input to DecodeFrom64 "Mzc5NDU3MDQtY2Y4Ni00YjJlLWE0YjUtMGRiMDIwNDkwMmM4" then it should work. your given GUID not encoded that is the issue.

Comment: yep you are correct, is there a way to check to see if the strnig is encoded?